# How do I use arima for simulating concrete values?

Tags: r, prediction, forecasting

We analyzed a data set with acf and pcf and saw the necessity to use arima.
Arima was executed and delivers coefficients. Now we want use it to forecast a random value. As I get it right the prediction of forecast or predict is the expected value. However, we want to create random values normally distributed around this prediction - as it was observed in the original data.
How can we handle this easy?

Thanks! best, F!

```
> summary(arima_res)
      Length Class  Mode     
coef        4    -none- numeric  
sigma2      1    -none- numeric  
var.coef   16    -none- numeric  
mask        4    -none- logical  
loglik      1    -none- numeric  
aic         1    -none- numeric  
arma        7    -none- numeric  
residuals 852    ts     numeric  
call        3    -none- call     
series      1    -none- character
code        1    -none- numeric  
n.cond      1    -none- numeric  
model      10    -none- list
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `forecast` package. Then use `simulate(fit)` where `fit` is the output from `arima()` or `Arima()`. Here is a quick example:

```
library(forecast)
fit <- Arima(USAccDeaths,order=c(0,1,1),seasonal=c(0,1,1))
plot(USAccDeaths,xlim=c(1973,1980),ylim=c(6000,12000))
for(i in 1:10)
  lines(simulate(fit,nsim=24),col="blue")
```

The means of the simulated values are equal to the point forecasts generated by `forecast(fit)`. The percentiles of the simulated values are equal to the prediction intervals obtained in the same way. (Not exactly, because this is a simulation, but asymptotically.)